# Codename One - days of month

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build a week view of the month with customized cells, so the Calendar class won't work for me.

I am having trouble knowing on which day the month starts. For example, January 1st was a Friday. Also, I need to know how many days a given month has.

Without telling me the exact code, can you tell me the variables or methods I could use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the actual code for the `Calendar` class here: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/

Just set `java.util.Calendar` to the right date then use the get method to get the day of the week.